# How do I make the two mesh lines rotate like independently BUT locally?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I'm trying to make two mesh lines with cubes as instances on them to rotate like one going -45 and the other 45, but not sure how to do this since i's like all 1 geoemetry?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you illustrate the final figure you want to obtain?

Comment: Like rotated on the Z axis, for the left one -45, right one positive 45

Comment: ok, but you mean individually or the whole line?

Comment: the one on the left or the right? https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pjFz.png ... or other?

Comment: if u wanna have quick answers (and you will get it) - provide a blend file.

Comment: YES LEMON THE ONE ON THE LEFT BUT LIKE OPPOSITE THOUGH

Comment: "like opposite"... what do you exactly mean?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already several rotations in your setting, we don't know what they are here for...

But, chaining with what you already have:

[image]

Just consider that, as you've 50 instances per line, either below 50 and turn in a direction or above and turn into its opposite.

(0.785 is 45° in radians)

Comment: THAK YOU LEMON, YOU ARE A GOD! 

Comment: @Homelander It seems at some point in time today your Caps Lock key is broken...